# MongoDB brew upgrade is lying

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

Homebrew claims I have the latest MongoDB (2.4.4). I have fully uninstalled and reinstalled MongoDB. Even when starting up mongo I get:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.4
```

However, this is a lie. If I do the following commands:

```
use admin
db.runCommand( {buildInfo: 1} )
```

It then proceeds to tell me I have version 2.0.6. This is a substantive problem for me as I need the aggregate framework which wasn't available until 2.2; do I need to do something to update the database separate from Mongo? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out all you really need to do is shutdown Mongo `mongo; db.shutdownServer({timeoutSecs: 1})`, and then run `mongod --upgrade`. Then you know, start it back up.

Comment: what you meant was "shutdown Mongo `mongod` - that's the server.  also in the shell you can run >  db.version() to see the server version.